# Thumbnail image is posted to wall instead of full image using facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to post (message and image) to facebook wall.

This is the url I used

```
 "https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?      access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&link="+imageUrl +"&privacy="+result);
```

I expected the image to post in full size,but it is posting Thumbnail image.

I tried with all the three parameters in (/feed) like "source","picture","link".
But the image is posting in thumbnail.

Did facebook graph api allow to post full size image?
If possible how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: I am trying to post on my feed,not on /photos

Comment: He's sent you the link to how you upload photos, the feed connection only shows a thumbnail

Comment: So,how can I upload full photo

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos an HTTP POST to PROFILE_ID/photos will give a full size photo to the timeline. You cannot have both a full size photo and a link. You can include a message.